# Do I use "Abends" or "Abende"?

Tags: word-choice

I want to say

> But there was no TV so the evenings were a bit boring.

I'm unsure if it is

> Aber es gab keinen Fernseher, also war **die Abende** ein bisschen langweilig. *or*
>   Aber es gab keinen Fernseher, also war **Abends** ein bisschen langweilig.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both words are fine. There are just some minor grammatical errors.

*Abende* is the plural of *Abend*. So, the verb must be conjugated accordingly.

> Aber es gab keinen Fernseher, also waren die Abende ein bisschen langweilig.

*Abends* is an adverb. It is spelled with a lower *a*. The sentence also requires *es* as subject (like in the first clause).

> Aber es gab keinen Fernseher, also war es abends ein bisschen langweilig.